# Why elements of typed List<> are cast to Object when used in the subclass

Tags: java, generics, types, casting

Can anyone explains why elements of typed `List<>` are cast to `Object` when used in a *subclass*?
This happens only when the parent class use *generics*.
In some how `type` of the class interferes with the `type` of the instance field.

```
public abstract class Parent<T> {
    protected List<String> myList = Arrays.asList("Hello", "World");

    void method1(){
        myList.get(0).substring(0, 1); //ok
    }
}


public class Child<T> extends Parent {
    void method2(){
        myList.get(0).substring(0, 1); //compilation error. myList.get(0) is of type Object and not of type String
        ((String) myList.get(0)).substring(0, 1); // works good, but why we need to cast 
    }
}
```

**UPDATE** 
As the accepted answer indicates, extending the generic `Parent<>`, and not `Parent`, will solve the problem.
A complete example using generics and extended row types:

```
public abstract class Parent<T extends MyObject> {
}

public class Child<T extends MyObject> extends Parent<T> {
}
```

Comment: Interesting. Even if you're extending the raw type `Parent`, it's curious to see that the compiler sees a connection to the type argument of the unrelated type argument to `List`

Comment: This is extensively answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it), including the relevant JLS quotes.

Comment: @ernest_k: See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.8 - when a raw type is used as the superclass, the erasure of the whole type is used, so *all* generics are lost.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks, that helps. I'm failing to see why it *has to* be like that, though.

Comment: @ernest_k: I suspect it simplifies things - bearing in mind that the point of raw types is for compatibility with code that doesn't understand generics at all.

Comment: @JonSkeet Makes sense. Thank you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
public class Child extends Parent
```

Because you've used the [*raw type*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html) `Parent`, all generics in the definitions of `Parent` are lost, effectively. From [section 4.8 of the JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.8):

> The superclasses (respectively, superinterfaces) of a raw type are the erasures of the superclasses (superinterfaces) of any of the parameterizations of the generic type.

That "erasures" part is the jargon for "you lose all the generics".

You need to specify a type argument when you refer to it in `Child`. For example you could keep a non-generic subclass:

```java
public class Child extends Parent<UUID>
```

Or make the subclass generic too:

```
public class Child<T> extends Parent<T>
```

Comment: Yes I need the Parent to be generic, but I need a Typed list to be present in the parent class, and avoid casting in all the child classes.

Comment: @Ermal: Did you *really* mean to call your type parameter `Integer`? That's a *highly* confusing type parameter name. But basically if you really need the parent to be generic (note that the type parameter isn't used anywhere you've shown it) then your subclass should use the generic superclass. I'll add an example of that in the answer.

Comment: Jon Skeet, you are right about the `Integer` on type parameter. My mistake, in my application I have `<T extends MyObject>` and I simplified with `Integer` leading to a non good example.
Making the `Child` generic too, do not solves the problem.
Anyway answer accepted, your answer was so clear about why it happens. (less was the push on non using generics :p) Thank you.  ( I am going to update the question cleaning all marginal doubts)

Comment: @Ermal: "Making the Child generic too, do not solves the problem." - It does, so long as you make sure you specify a type argument for `Parent`.

Comment: @Ermal: I've fixed my answer to account for your question edit now, but in future it's better to leave a question alone - or maybe just add something - if an edit would make an answer non-sensical, as it did in this case.